# Is it possible to allow only specific orientations based on view controller on iOS 13?

Tags: ios, swift

So with previous versions of iOS, it was possible to set which orientations were allowed on a per-viewcontroller basis using the supportedInterfaceOrientations variable.

Apple's own documentation indicates that we 'shouldn't' use the old orientation mask approach, suggesting we upgrade to traits instead.  Unfortunately, I don't actually know anything about traits yet, and while I'll obviously need to pick them up, I need to get this done.  Is there any way, with an iOS 13 app, to specify allowed orientations on a per-view controller basis?

Comment: Where does Apple say `supportedInterfaceOrientations` shouldn't be used? https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621435-supportedinterfaceorientations

Comment: @rbaldwin https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiinterfaceorientationmask "Starting in iOS 8, you should employ the UITraitCollection and UITraitEnvironment APIs, and size class properties as used in those APIs, instead of using UIInterfaceOrientation constants or otherwise writing your app in terms of interface orientation."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out the old methods still, work, there was just a wrinkle I'd screwed up on.  Because I was using a UINavigationController as my root, instead of calling those methods directly, I needed to create a delegate for the navigation controller.